# How to save list of extracted features in hdf5 file python

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, hdf5, h5py

I am extracting some features from an audio file and save them in a list and then saving a list in hdf5 file but it cause an error. Previously I am directly saving features in a hdf5 file but it just overwrite all the values and save only the last one.

```
ampList = []
 mffcslist = []
 centroidlist = []
 i = 0


    ampList.append(Xdb)        # saving extracted feature in a list
    mffcslist.append(mfccs)    
    centroidlist.append(spectral_centroids)

with h5py.File('C:/Users/Aweem Ashar/Desktop/feature.h5', 'a') as f:
    f.close()

    for i in range(len(audio_path)):
        #print(ampList[i])

        f.create_dataset("amplitude", data=ampList[i])
        f.create_dataset("MffC", data=mffcslist[i])
        f.create_dataset("spectral", data=centroidlist[i])

    # plt.show()      # To view Wave graph
```

Comment: Please check your code. You have `f.close()` immediately after you open the file. Here is your primary problem: you are using `f.create_dataset()` in a loop with the same 3 dataset names each time. That's OK for the first loop. You need to add data to existing datasets or use new dataset names on subsequent loops .Otherwise the dataset previously created is overwritten. You can resize with `Dataset.resize()`. Read the h5py documentation on resizable datasets (http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#resizable-datasets).

Answer (score 4):

I didn't look at your code that closely when I wrote my comment. I just realized you are loading your list data one element at a time. There are much better/faster ways to do it with Numpy arrays. I don't know what kind of data you're working with, so created a very simple example with a few floats in `ampList`. I use `np.asarray()` to convert the list to a Numpy array and load into the dataset in 1 shot. Much easier and compact. This method (with `np.asarray()`) will work for any list with elements of a common type (all floats or all ints).

**My simple example:**

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

ampList = [ 20., 11., 33., 40., 100. ]

with h5py.File('SO_58092765.h5','w') as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset("amplitude", data=np.asarray(ampList) )
```

**A Better Approach:**
The example above addresses your basic question (how to copy the list data into a HDF dataset). However, I think there is a better approach for your scenario. I assume you have amplitude, MffC, and spectral data for each and every audio file, AND it would be convenient to have that data associated with the audio file name. If so, that's where HDF5 and mixed format datatypes are so powerful.

I created a second example (below) to show how you can save mixed data in a single dataset. I assumed the following datatypes (to make the example interesting):

- Audio file name: String
- amplitude: Float
- MffC: Integer
- Spectral (centroid): Float array of shape (3,)

This example creates 2 HDF5 files:

- **SO_58092765_3ds.h5**: saves each List as a separate dataset.
- **SO_58092765_1ds.h5**: saves all List data in a single dataset, with each List written to a separate Field/Column.

The second method uses a Numpy datatype (dtype) to define the name and datatype of each column of data in the HDF5 dataset. The dtype is then used to create an empty dataset. Each List is written to the dataset by referencing the field name.

**Second example:**

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

fileList = [ 'audio1.mp3', 'audio2.mp3', 'audio11.mp3', 'audio21.mp3','audio22.mp3' ]
ampList =   [ 20., 11., 33., 40., 100. ]
mffcslist = [ 12,   8,   9,  14,  33 ]
centroidlist = [ (0.,0.,0.), (1.,0.,0.), 
                 (0.,1.,0.), (0.,1.,0.),
                 (1.,1.,1.),]

# create SO_58092765_3ds.h5: 
with h5py.File('SO_58092765_3ds.h5','w') as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset("amplitude", data=np.asarray(ampList) )
    h5f.create_dataset("MffC", data=np.asarray(mffcslist) )
    h5f.create_dataset("spectral", data=np.asarray(centroidlist) )   

# create SO_58092765_1ds.h5 with ds_dtype:
ds_dtype =  np.dtype( [("audiofile",'S20'), ("amplitude",float), 
                       ("MffC",int), ("spectral",float, (3,)) ] )

with h5py.File('SO_58092765_1ds.h5','w') as h5f:
    ds = h5f.create_dataset("test_data", shape=(len(ampList),), dtype=ds_dtype )

    ds['audiofile'] = np.asarray(fileList)
    ds['amplitude'] = np.asarray(ampList)
    ds['MffC'] = np.asarray(mffcslist)
    ds['spectral'] = np.asarray(centroidlist)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion.please help me out from this                                                                                                                                                                               
     line 61, in <module>
    f.create_dataset("amplitude", data=np.asarray(ampList))
  File "C:\Users\Aweem Ashar\FeaturesLibrosa\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
 return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1025,28) into shape (1025)

Comment: Aweem, without seeing your code/data, it's hard to diagnose specifically. The "could not broadcast" message means the elements of the input (ampList) can not be reshaped to match the output ("amplitude" dataset). The error suggests dataset "amplitude" has shape (1025) but the input list "ampList" has shape (1025,28). Is "ampList" a Python List or a Numpy array? What kind of objects are in "ampList"? Did you try to run my examples?

Comment: Yes I have tried your solution and post the code below kindly review it

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from glob import glob
import librosa as lb
import sklearn
import librosa.display
import librosa
import h5py
import numpy as np
dir = 'C:\\Users\\Aweem Ashar\\Desktop\\recordingd'
audio_path = glob(dir + '/*.wav')
ampList = []
mffcslist = []
centroidlist = []
for file in range(0, len(audio_path)):
    x, sr = lb.load(audio_path[file])
    print(type(x), type(sr))
    librosa.display.waveplot(x, sr=sr)
    X = librosa.stft(x)
    Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
    librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='hz')
    spectral_centroids = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(x, sr=sr)[0]
    spectral_centroids.shape
    frames = range(len(spectral_centroids))
    t = librosa.frames_to_time(frames)

    def normalize(x, axis=0):
        return sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale(x, axis=axis)
    librosa.display.waveplot(x, sr=sr, alpha=0.4)
    plt.plot(t, normalize(spectral_centroids), color='r')
    mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(x, sr=sr)
    print(mfccs.shape)
    librosa.display.specshow(mfccs, sr=sr, x_axis='time')
    ampList.append(Xdb)
    mffcslist.append(mfccs)
    centroidlist.append(spectral_centroids)
with h5py.File('C:/Users/Aweem Ashar/Desktop/feature.h5', 'w') as f:
    f.create_dataset("amplitude", data=np.asarray(ampList))
    f.create_dataset("MFCC", data=np.asarray(mffcslist))
    f.create_dataset("SpectralCentroid", data=np.asarray(centroidlist))
```

Answer (score 1):

Aweem, I'm not familiar with `librosa` or `sklearn` so can't debug all your code. When working with something new, use a minimally complete verifiable example (MCVE)  to confirm behavior with simple data sets. They are much easier to diagnose.

To do that, I simplified the `for` loop in your second post; reorganizing and removing what I thought was unnecessary. Also, you don't need to loop over all the images. Change the `glob()` call to get 1 (or a few) images. The shape of `Xdb` (saved to `ampList`) should show why Numpy `asarray()` tries to broadcast the shape (and why you get an error). If not, post the output for review.

Finally, you should add a comment to `create_dataset("amplitude")` to verify that the other 2 `create_dataset()` calls work. Good luck.

```
dir = 'C:\\Users\\Aweem Ashar\\Desktop\\recordingd'
# change this to get 1 wav file:
audio_path = glob(dir + '/*.wav') 
ampList = []
mffcslist = []
centroidlist = []
for file in range(0, len(audio_path)):
    x, sr = lb.load(audio_path[file])
    print(x, sr)
    X = librosa.stft(x)
    Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
    print (Xdb.shape)
    ampList.append(Xdb)

    spectral_centroids = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(x, sr=sr)[0]
    print (spectral_centroids.shape)   
    centroidlist.append(spectral_centroids)

    mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(x, sr=sr)
    print (mfccs.shape)
    mffcslist.append(mfccs)  

with h5py.File('C:/Users/Aweem Ashar/Desktop/feature.h5', 'w') as f:
    f.create_dataset("amplitude", data=np.asarray(ampList))
    f.create_dataset("MFCC", data=np.asarray(mffcslist))
    f.create_dataset("SpectralCentroid", data=np.asarray(centroidlist))
```